# How to assert a header contains specific value in Chakram

Tags: javascript, web-api-testing, chakram

I have an API which has a response header of `Keep-Alive` with the following values

`Keep-Alive →timeout=15, max=100`

I want to assert that the values timeout is at least 10 and at most 100. Earlier I was using Postman BDD library and had this code

```
let keepAlive = response.getHeader("Keep-Alive");

        // Make sure it contains "max=##"
        let match = /max=(\d+)/.exec(keepAlive);
        expect(match).to.be.an("array").and.not.empty;

        // Make sure the max is between 98 and 100
        let max = parseInt(match[1]);
        expect(max).to.be.at.least(15).and.at.most(100);
```

However, if I use `Chakram`, the `getHeader` function errors out with `TypeError: response.getHeader is not a function` . Does anyone has any idea how to get a header value using Chakram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to get a header value in Chakram. e.g. to validate if the response is in json format.
`expect(response).to.have.header('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'));`

The response returned by Chakram is a promise and should be handled as such. So getting the 'keep-Alive' header value:

```
return chakram.get(serverUrl, params)
.then( chakramResponse => {
    let keepAlive = chakramResponse.response.headers['Keep-Alive'];
    let match = /max=(\d+)/.exec(keepAlive);
    return expect(match).to.be.an("array").and.not.empty;
    let max = parseInt(match[1]);
    return expect(max).to.be.at.least(15).and.at.most(100); 
});
```

Comment: The timeout value changes so I cannot hard code it to to something like this.

Comment: @demouser123 I have updated my response. Please have a look

Comment: Still getting the error `response.headers` is not a function.

Comment: Fixed it. I had two variables named `headers` that created an isse. Renaming other corrected this.